# MYSQL Select Left Join - How to get 2 rows from same table using 2 diff ids?

Tags: mysql

**EDIT - SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT a.content as title, c.content as title_text, b.content as content FROM content_big AS b LEFT JOIN content_small AS a on a.id = 7 LEFT JOIN content_small AS c on c.id = 8 WHERE b.id = 1
```

I'm trying to do a Select like this:

- Get *column content* from **table content_big** where ID = 1
- Get *column content* from **table content_small** where ID = 7
- Get *column content* from **table content_small** where ID = 8

Is possible to get these data using 1 select?
I'm trying some variations of this query:

```
 SELECT content_small.content as title, content_small.content as title, content_big.content as content
 FROM content_big LEFT JOIN
      content_small
      on content_small.id = 7 LEFT JOIN
      content_small
      on content_small.id = 8
 WHERE content_small.content = 1
```

But I'm getting this error

> *Not unique table/alias: 'content_small'*

Comment: Do you want this all in one row or they could be in different rows?

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question- or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Alias your tables on the joins, like so:

```
SELECT cs1.content as title, cs1.content as title, content_big.content as content
 FROM content_big LEFT JOIN
      content_small cs1
      on content_small.id = 7 LEFT JOIN
      content_small cs2
      on content_small.id = 8
 WHERE cs2.content = 1
```

Then you won't have the naming conflict.

Comment: He want `from the same table`!!

Comment: I'm aliasing the tables.  Notice cs1 and cs2 are both copies of the same table.  Here's more on aliasing: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp